# Value attribute of Struts select not working

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

So I have this like in a .jsp file:

```
<s:select name="dataObject.a" id="a" list="dataObject.aList" value="dataObject.a"/>
```

And the desired behavior is that the user's preference (stored at dataObject.a) would end up being the initial value of the select element on the page. However, despite the appropriate option in the select element having the attribute 'selected="selected"' it does not display as selected. Any thoughts? All browsers have this issue.

EDIT: Adding the generated HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="class1">
        <label id="aLabel" class="labelPadding" for="a">A:</label>
    </span>
    <select name="dataObject.a" id="a">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you do any DOM manipulation after the page is loaded?

Comment: Just basic event binding to the buttons on the page and focusing on the first element of the form.

Comment: Post the generated HTML.

Comment: Added. I can't add the whole document as I would have to redact way too much info, so I just posted the relevant section. Hopefully this is sufficient!

Comment: What value is set when you submit a form?

Comment: If it is submitted as it is on page load, the field a is null. If I manually select a value, the appropriate field makes it to the code.

Comment: it should not be submitted on page load, but when you press on the submit button.

Comment: Correct. What I mean is that if I do not change the value of the select before submitting, it submits the field as null. Otherwise, the appropriate value is submitted.

Comment: Which case is posted HTML?

Comment: The posted HTML is at page load.

Comment: Can you get a value of the select element on button click or on submit event, what is the value?

Comment: It appears to be undefined at first. But it doesn't change when I select a value. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong there.